# jenkinsfile parameter properties not configured in jenkins server at initial branch creation

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-workflow

I have configured jenkinsfile with below properties, but it doesn't apply on jenkins server when creating a new branch from master branch.

```
#!groovy

properties([[$class: 'ParametersDefinitionProperty',
    parameterDefinitions: [
        [$class: 'StringParameterDefinition', name: 'isValid', defaultValue: 'false']
    ]
]])

node {
    stage 'Checkout'        
        checkout scm
    .....
    .....
}
```

After branch created in git, the branch is visible in the jenkins server with **Build Now** option.

Once I run the branch first time from the jenkins server, it is changed into **Build with Parameters** option.

Is there anything I missed to configure in jenkinsfile? Why the parameters not configured in the jenkins server at branch creation?

Comment: This is existing Jenkins issue. Please refer to https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40574

Answer (score 3):

You can get around this by using `params.isValid` instead of `env.isValid`.

Answer (score 2):

Something I've used to get around this is to check if `env.BUILD_NUMBER == "1"` on a branch and then set some default values for my parameters to use on the initial run of that branch.  For example:

```
node {
  properties([
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(artifactDaysToKeepStr: '', artifactNumToKeepStr: '', daysToKeepStr: '15')),
    parameters([
      string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'PLATFORM')
    ])
  ])

  stage("Testing") {
    // set a default for PLATFORM if it's the first build of a PR
    // as a workaround to parameters not being available on first run of build
    if (env.BUILD_NUMBER == "1") {
      PLATFORM = ''
    }

    if (PLATFORM.empty) {
      ....
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to still be broken as of 2019. You can work around it by having an initial stage in your pipeline that sets the parameter value back into the environment variable. After that, you can reference it normally in subsequent stages.

```
parameters {
    string(name: 'SOME_VAR', defaultValue: 'foo', description: 'A custom environment variable')
}

....

stage('Verifying Environment Variables') {
    // This is too work around a jenkins bug on the first build of a multi-branch job
    // https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40574 - it is marked resolved but the last comment says it doesn't work for declaritive pipelines
    environment {
        SOME_VAR = "${params.SOME_VAR}"
    }
    steps {
        script {
            env.SOME_VAR = env.SOME_VAR
        }
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Declarative Pipeline, just add the following stage as your first stage.

```
stage('Preparations') {
  steps {
    echo 'Initialize parameters as environment variables due to https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41929'
    evaluate """${def script = ""; params.each { k, v -> script += "env.${k} = \"${v}\"\n" }; return script}"""
  }
}
```

This issue is being tracked on [JENKINS-41929](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41929).

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue of fist time property initialization in the pipeline script.
Looks like best way is like this, as example I have SKIP_RUN parameter, step in each pipeline that when I update job pipeline I could run it and properties where updated in the Jenkins UI:

**Note:** Main thing here is give initial value if property is 'null' "def skipRun = params.SKIP_RUN ?: true"

```
properties([
    parameters([
        booleanParam(name: 'SKIP_RUN', description: 'Skips all stages. Used to update parameters in case of changes.', defaultValue: false),
    ])
])

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('skip run') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // First time when added 'params.SKIP_RUN' will be null, setting value to true when 'SKIP_RUN' is not eat initialized to skip build.
                    def skipRun = params.SKIP_RUN ?: true
                    echo "SKIP_RUN: '${skipRun}';"
                    if(skipRun) {
                        currentBuild.description = "SKIPPED"
                        currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
                        error("Aborting the build - SKIP_RUN is set to true")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Do job stage") {
           //...
       }
   }

}
```

**Update: 2023-04-25 (script v2 - Improved version)**. Not sure why but initial answer (script block above) started not working - as always SKIP_RUN started to be null for me. So here is improved answer of "SKIP_BUILD" property which I use to skip build all jobs to initialize Jenkins job parameter changes. Script check for null property also it check if in previous build this property existed - if not that means we need to SKIP_RUN and initialize property:

```
properties([
        parameters([
            booleanParam(name: 'SKIP_RUN', description: 'Skips all stages. Used to update parameters in case of changes.', defaultValue: false)
        ])
    ])
    
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('skip run') {
            steps {
                script {
                    try {
                        // Set skipRun to true only if SKIP_RUN is not initialized, the pipeline is not running for the first time, and the previous build did not have SKIP_RUN set to true.
                        echo "SKIP_RUN: '${params.SKIP_RUN}';"
                        echo "previousBuild: '${currentBuild.rawBuild.previousBuild}';"
        
                        def noSkipParamInPreviousBuild = false
                        if (currentBuild?.rawBuild?.previousBuild?.actions != null) {
                            noSkipParamInPreviousBuild = !currentBuild.rawBuild.previousBuild.getAction(ParametersAction.class)?.getParameter("SKIP_RUN")
                        }
                        echo "noSkipParamInPreviousBuild: '${noSkipParamInPreviousBuild}';"
        
                        def skipRun = currentBuild.rawBuild.previousBuild == null || (params.SKIP_RUN == null && noSkipParamInPreviousBuild) || params.SKIP_RUN == true
                        echo "skipRun: ${skipRun}';"
        
                        if(skipRun) {
                            currentBuild.description = "SKIPPED"
                            currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
                            error("Aborting the build - SKIP_RUN is set to ${skipRun}")
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        echo "Exception message: ${e.getMessage()}"
                        throw e
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Do job stage") {
            //...
        }
    }

}
```

**Note:** You will need to Approve some classes/methods/scripts to be executed in the Jenkins.